# How can I add Xamarin Forms to F# Xamarin Android project?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, f#, nuget, installation

1. Create an app using the "Blank App (Android) F#" template in Visual Studio 2019
2. Try to add Xamarin Forms
   [image: try]
3. Xamarin Forms cannot be added?
   [image]

What happened? How can I add Xamarin Forms into an F# Xamarin Android project?

Comment: I think you do not understand how Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Forms work please take a look at this https://applikeysolutions.com/blog/xamarin-forms-vs-xamarin-native-what-fits-you-best

Comment: A Xamarin.Forms F# template doesn't exist. I'm trying to recreate one.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but you should definitely look at https://fsprojects.github.io/Fabulous/ if you want to to Xamarin.Forms with F#.

Comment: I'm debugging Fabulous itself; I can't use it directly. https://github.com/fsprojects/Fabulous/issues/385

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot add the xamarin forms nuget packages to you xamarin native project.

The right process is you can create a xamarin forms project, then you can add the xamarin forms package in the xamarin android platform like this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: There is no corresponding template for F#.

Comment: @Happypig375, Yes, you should use C# to achieve that.

Comment: This problem doesn't exist with csprojs.

Comment: With the Xamarin.Forms template, Xamarin.Forms _is_ installed to the Xamarin.Android project. I'm trying to recreate it in F#.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider [Xamarin.Forms Embedding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-forms).

It enables a Xamarin.Forms' ContentPage to be incorporated into a Xamarin.IOS or Xamarin.Android app.

I have used it before and it had a significant performance cost to it when loading the content page.

Here's the [Android documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-forms#android).

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    public static string FolderPath { get; private set; }

    public static MainActivity Instance;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        Instance = this;

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        ...

        Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment mainPage = new NotesPage().CreateSupportFragment(this);
        SupportFragmentManager
            .BeginTransaction()
            .Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_frame_layout, mainPage)
            .Commit();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: How can I achieve this if I can't install Xamarin.Forms itself?